# Blender Retopo Nightmare

Tags: mesh, topology

[image: This is driving me crazy. I've been doing retopology for a model but anything near this bottom pinch turns all jagged and rough.]

This is driving me crazy. I've been doing retopology for a model but anything near this bottom pinch turns all jagged and rough. I can't figure out how to fix this issue. I've tried changing the normals but it doesn't help. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should make concentric circles with some successive extrusions (<kbd>E</kbd>) and scales (<kbd>S</kbd>), and the more the circle is central the more you scale it on the Z axis (<kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd>), and you should even scale the last ones at zero (<kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>)

[image]

Comment: kbd formatting for keyboard keys please. E.g. <kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>Z</kbd>.

Comment: @moonboots You want to have [this](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/391/30849).